# Can't get HockeyApp working on iOS with Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, hockeyapp

I try to use HockeyApp on a iOS project with xamarin forms.

It's working fine on android, but I can't get it working on iOS.

Here's my AppDelegate code for HockeyApp:

```
var manager = BITHockeyManager.SharedHockeyManager;
manager.Configure("----");
manager.CrashManager.Init();
manager.LogLevel = BITLogLevel.Verbose;
manager.CrashManager.CrashManagerStatus = BITCrashManagerStatus.AutoSend;
manager.StartManager();
manager.Authenticator.AuthenticateInstallation(); 

if (BITHockeyManager.SharedHockeyManager.CrashManager.DidCrashInLastSession)
{
    runInSafeMode = true;
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Then, later in my code I throw an NotYetImplementedException.

The exception is correctly catched and send to the server on android, but I can't get it working on iOS.

BITHockeyManager.SharedHockeyManager.CrashManager.DidCrashInLastSession is always false.

I also tried without the debugger attached as I read that the debugger catch exception before the SDK, still not working.

Any ideas ?

**EDIT : Additional informations**

I tried Visual Studio Mobile Center, working fine on android, same issue with iOS, HasCrashedInLastSessionAsync always to false

I moved the throw exception outside of the main method, just in case of, still the same problem, exception looks like not detected by the API

I disabled the debugging in addition of not attaching the debugger, I also tried to compile in Release, nothing new.

I removed the call to Init and AuthenticateInstallation, still the same problem.

Comment: Try removing `manager.CrashManager.Init()` and `manager.Authenticator.AuthenticateInstallation()`. I also do not set the `LogLevel` but that should not hurt anything. I believe `manager.Authenticator` stuff is only needed if you plan to do stuff other than exception handling and analytics.

Comment: @hvaughan3, thanks for the reply, I tried without them without success, still not getting DidCrashInLastSession to true.

Comment: And the crashes are not showing up in the Hockey App site portal after relaunching the app? (You must relaunch the app after an **unhandled** exception crashes the app for the exception to show up)

Comment: @hvaughan3 no and more important DidCrashInLastSession remains to false. So the next time my application boot, she can't boot in safe mode to allow the SDK to send the exception. I tried Visual Studio Mobile Center and I have the exact same problem, everything looks like correct but when I read Crashes.HasCrashedInLastSessionAsync() it's set to false. Whenever with or without the debugger attached. It almost looks like the unhandled exception is not caught by SDK.

Comment: You are not catching the exceptions right? Not sure how it would work on Android if you were but just wanted to make sure. I cannot imagine what else would cause problems other than maybe the iOS Linker which you could try disabling to rule that out.

Comment: Did you have any other third-party library which can detect crash in your iOS project?

Comment: @EmmanuelIstace did you get any solution for this issue? I am also facing the same issue in integrating hockeyApp on iOS in Xamarin forms.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you put your Hockey Init code?

I got it working with `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();` after the Hockey Init in my `FinishedLaunching` method.

Something like this:

```
var manager = BITHockeyManager.SharedHockeyManager;
...
manager.StartManager();
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, but I don't work for that company anymore. I will fw the message to my ex-collegues

Comment: Ok thank you :) if it's the case please set it as Correct Answer